# How to override embedded style in chrome?

Tags: css, browser, google-chrome, markup

Chrome appends an stylesheet and it make a lot of problems for me. for example this selector

```
html>body, html>body * {background-color:#ffffff !important}
```

is one oe the things I can't override in my own styles. Anyone has a solution for that?

Comment: You can set the background color, not sure where the code you posted comes from: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnuFE/

Answer (score 1):

Though all browsers have a default stylesheet for elements, none of them set the background color as !important which wouldn't allow you to change it. What you show must be getting attached from elsewhere, not Chrome, but, without a link or the complete markup, anything we tell you would just be a wild guess.